# Show form in Android service with Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, service

my project needs to scan beacon devices just like the AndroidBeaconServiceDemo sample.

But in some occasions, when detecting specific beacons, I need to interact with the user, showing a form with a radio button and other visual components. A simple notification is not enough in this case.

The question is: is it possible to create/show a form inside an Android **service**?

Any other sugestions to accomplish this job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My suggestion is to start the activity that is your Delphi app (as opposed to the service) from the service

Comment: Android apps that interact with the user have a host that stays awake while the user is using the app. Services are for background processing that occurs when the user is not interacting with the app. Services can do interprocess communication with the host app where the UI is, and wake it up under the circumstances you require by posting a notification. This is standard and you will find lots of examples of this.

Comment: Thanks @FreddieBell, but what if the user closes the host app? It can be woken, i.e., started from a notification? Could you point me an example that works like that?

Comment: @DaveNottage has extensive demos you can follow. https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/AndroidLocation

Comment: And there's my own answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466609